# What is the difference between string "match" and string "equal" in TCL

Tags: string, shell, scripting, tcl

In TCL what is the difference between string "match" and string "equal".
They are almost same so I am not able to detect the difference between them.

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

`string equal` compares two strings character by character and returns 1 if they both contain the same characters (case sensitive: can be overridden).

`string match` compares a string against a `glob`-style pattern and returns 1 if the string matches the pattern.

In a degenerate case, a `string match` with only non-special characters in the pattern is equivalent to a `string equal`.

Documentation:
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl string matching:*

- `*` matches a sequence of zero or more characters
- `?` matches a single character
- `[chars]` matches a single character in the set given by *chars* (^ does *not* negate; a range can be given as *a-z*)
- `\x` matches the character *x*, even if that character is special (one of `*?[]\`)

Answer (score 0):

already answered in 
[TCL string match vs regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411482/tcl-string-match-vs-regexps)
Regexp are slower than base function. So you should avoid regex for equal check

Comment: While it's good advice in general, it has basically nothing to do with this question, since it isn't about regular expression matching.